# UINavigationController not popping view on back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController.  I've got a UIViewController that I've pushed onto the stack using pushViewController.  The previous view controller has a backBarButtonItem simply titled "Cancel."

While the new view animates in correctly, when I tap Cancel, the navigation bar animates as if the view was popped, but the new view doesn't go away.  Do I need to implement a delegate somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

First Create a `UIButton` then Create one `UIBarButtonItem` with Custom view, considering `UIButton` as custom view for `UIBarButtonItem`.

Consider button to target event for popping view controller.

`UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`
`button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);`
`[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dots.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
`[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backBarButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

`UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];`

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;`

`- (void)backBarButton:(id)sender {`
`NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);`
`self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
`}`

Comment: I think it could be a simpler answer. Just adding the [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; call in the button clicked event would solve the problem.