# UINavigationController: View not popping, but title pops

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UINavigationController and a UIViewController pushed onto the stack with pushViewController. When I click the default back button, the title appropriately animates away, but the view does not pop. Is there something that I am missing?

There is a solution here: [UINavigationController not popping view on back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301993/uinavigationcontroller-not-popping-view-on-back-button), but this involves overwriting the button itself. It doesn't seem to be very good design. Isn't the back button supposed to pop the view automatically?

-K

Comment: Can you post your code where you push the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to an exception occurring - CoreAnimation eats the exceptions, so carefully check your console output for error messages.